# Converting DayOfWeek enum to a string repesenting the day

Tags: vb.net, date, dayofweek, select-case

I was wondering if there was a way to directly convert the integer `DayOfWeek` returns into a string representing the day like Monday, Tuesday etc.

Sample code:

```
MessageBox.Show(Date.Today.DayOfWeek)
```

This will return `6` (as of today). Is there a way to directly convert this into `Saturday`, for example? I don't really care what it really converts it into, but I want to do away with my Select Case:

```
Select Case Date.Today.DayOfWeek
     Case 0
         day = "Sunday"
     Case 1
         day = "Monday"
     Case 2
         day = "Tuesday"
     Case 3
         day = "Wednesday"
     Case 4
         day = "Thursday"
     Case 5
         day = "Friday"
     Case 6
         day = "Saturday"
     Case Else
         day = "Apocalypse: we're all boned."
 End Select
```

Thanks :)

Comment: I don't think that the .NET framework supports your `Case Else`. Too bad...

Comment: Probably something MS should look at... it'll happen one day. Although I do get errors using `day` later on in the code if it's not there :P

Comment: Nothing is wrong with using `Case Else`. There are easier ways to get day name. However as Jon pointed out, DayOfWeek is an enum type, so it will never be anything other than 0 to 6.

Comment: And just to emphasize what has also been been said by others, Sunday is 0, not 7. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simpler way:

```
Dim day As String = Date.Today.DayOfWeek.ToString()
```

Comment: @ghord this technique just transform an enumeration to a string value; you probably would do something like `DateTime.Today.ToString("dddd", new CultureInfo("pt-br"))`

Answer (score 13):

DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.[GetDayName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.getdayname.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

There's a DateTime format for that: dddd

```
Dim date1 As Date = #08/29/2008 7:27:15PM#
date1.ToString("dddd", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"))
```

With the CultureInfo you can get it in a specific language (it's optional)

For more info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#ddddSpecifier

Answer (score 0):

[`DateTime.DayOfWeek`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) doesn't return an integer - it returns an enum of type [`DayOfWeek`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx). I'd expect that to be converted into the name automatically, but maybe this is a VB subtlety; maybe something to do with using `Date` instead of `DateTime`? Try this:

```
MessageBox.Show(DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek.ToString())
```

This won't be culture-sensitive though - it will always just display the name of enum value, in English. If that's not good for you, use Zyphrax or itowlson's solution.

Comment: This will return the invariant (US English) name; fine for debugging or storing in a database or whatever, but if he's displaying it he should be using something that localises the string.

Comment: @itowlson: I was just editing to say something similar, but less specifically. Not *every* UI needs to be localised, IMO. There are plenty of apps which will only ever be in one language (think internal apps for non-international companies). If that language is English, that makes life even easier.

Comment: Thanks. And this code is just to reference some TextBoxes in my form in a timetable order. The actual data going to be displayed is coming from a database :)

Answer (score 0):

`Date.Today.DayOfWeek.ToString` will give you what you're looking for. Nice and easy.

Answer (score -3):

Just in case others looked at this example.  I believe it should be Case 0 for Sunday.

```
Case 0 
    day = "Sunday"
```

Comment: What you have here is a comment on the question, not an answer. Posting comments as answer to circumvent the rules inevitably leads to moderator intervention.

Comment: Sounds good.  But I searched for this example code, and it was incorrect beyond the question.  I spent some time figuring it out.  I think it should be pointed out for future users, even it the question was already answered.